# Expectation of multipliction of two functions

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Let $(X_n)$ is a martingale,such that $Y_n = X_n-X_{n-1}$ is a $L^2$ function for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $E[Y_mY_n] =0 $ whenever m is not equal to n.

I tried it but I am not able to conclude anything. Where do we have to use that $Y_n$ is in $L^2$ ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Let $n<m$. Then $E(Y_nY_m)=E(X_n-X_{n-1})(Y_m-Y_{m-1})$ Condition on $\mathcal F_{m-1}$ and note that $$E((X_n-X_{n-1})(Y_m-Y_{m-1})|\mathcal F_{m-1})$$ $$=(X_n-X_{n-1})E((Y_m-Y_{m-1})|\mathcal F_{m-1})=(X_n-X_{n-1})\times 0$$ because $E(Y_m| \mathcal F_{m-1})=Y_{m-1}$ by martingale property.

Comment: Where are you using the fact that $Y_n$ is in $L^2$ ?? Did you make some typo ?You are writing $Y_m= Y_m- Y_{m-1}$.

Comment: $EY_nY_m$ exists because $E|Y_nY_m| \leq \sqrt {EY_n^{2}} \sqrt {EY_m^{2}}$. Without the assumption that $Y_n \in L^{2}$ you don't even know that $EY_nY_m$ exists. @HitendraKumar

Comment: So you proved that conditional expectation with respect to $F_{m-1}$ is zero.Is it true that if conditional expectation is zero then expectation is zero ?

Comment: @HitendraKumar Yes, we always have $EX=E(E(X|\mathcal G))$ for any random variable $X$ with finite mean and any sigma algebra $\mathcal G$. This is one of the fundamental facts about conditional expectations.